# Safari Mobile Web Inspector not displaying Element Tab

Tags: mobile-safari, safari-web-inspector

The `Elements` tab (as well as others) in the Safari Mobile Web Inspector is not displaying. I can only see the `Console`, `Sources`, and `Audit` tabs. The `Sources` tab isn't showing any of the sources for the site.

I am trying to debug the styling for an app using Webview and Cordova. I have tried inspecting a Safari mobile web page and the same thing happens.

Workspace:

- iOS: 14.6
- iPhone: 8
- macOS: Big Sur 11.4
- Xcode: 12.5 beta 2
- Safari (desktop): 14.1.1

This was working previously. The only thing that has changed is that I updated my macOS version. I can use the web inspector as intended on Safari (desktop).

Answer (score 3):

One solution I found was to install the latest [Safari Preview Technology](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/).

Comment: Thanks! It works for me too. I can run Safari Technology Preview on a Mac OS Big Sur 11.4 then from the Develop tab I can choose my iPhone X iOS 14.6 and all tabs are showing in the Web Inspector.